# Execution failed for task (Android Studio)

Tags: android-studio

Пытаюсь сделать приложение по видеоуроку с firebase,но в итоге вылазят ошибки. Гуглил, пытался исправить, но так и не получилось.

[image: Сами ошибки]

[image: project]

[![]module[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/daQm5.png)][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/daQm5.png)

Comment: Код надо текстом выкладывать, а не картинкой. Так как нельзя например скопировать что то из текста ошибки или кода. По сути проблемы - возможно сервера лежат или заблокированы. Попробуйте через VPN собрать

Comment: Спасибо за совет и комментарий ,сейчас попробую

Comment: Также стоит проверить, что в build.gradle из app модуля подключено плагин гугло-сервисов

Comment: apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'  есть ,если вы об этом. Через vpn не запустился

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего проблема была s SigningReport . По умолчанию не было тасков, стояла галочка ,чтобы они не создавались ,в итоге создавал в ручную ,в чём скорее всего и была проблема. Проблема решилась ,когда я по новой создал проект и убрал галочку c
Do not build gradle task list during gradle sync[image: введите сюда описание изображения]